# Using Matching to Conduct a Sub Group Analysis

Tags: r, regression, matching, propensity-scores

[Moved from stack overflow)
While I have done a good amount of reading regarding the usage of PSM, I am still struggling a bit to see if it can be used in my application.

I am trying to analyze the impact of an advertising campaign on in-store sales lift. While I know Propensity Scores are typically used in non-randomized studies, this study will be randomized (some stores will randomly see the advertising campaign, some will not). I have sales level data by store (such as pre-sales volume etc), and I want to conduct a sub-group analysis, to make sure I am comparing stores that behave similarly (start out at same level of sales volume, received roughly the same amount of spend, etc).
Can anyone advise the best way to go about this?

I was initially thinking about using propensity scores to formulate the matching, but I know that seems counter-intuitive in this randomized setting.  However, in what way should I go about making a matched control group based on those variables? Would it still use the MatchIt package- but does that strictly use some variation of Propensity Scores?

In addition, after a matched set, would a simple multiple regression be the best means of finding the treatment effect?

Any thoughts/help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You are exactly right, Why do you have to use matching/propensity score matching (PSM) when it's randomized? Since, Randomization controls for both observed and unobserved variables I don't see a need for PSM

Comment: Thanks for your response, I guess what I am really trying to get at is what is the best way to go about making a control group to use for comparison to the treatment group? Lets say I have access to 4000 stores, of which only 1,000 receive treatment, and I want to get the best estimate of treatment by using the most apt control group (out of a possible size of 3,000).  I was thinking of performing some sort of matching to  balance baseline covariates. Would this be a good way of finding the right control group? If so, what matching and post matching process would be best to do this?

Comment: Matching for subgroup analysis should be highly supervised and completely rational and not based on a regression model (IMO). As mentioned on SO and as forecaster points out, your randomization has balanced the groups for possible confounders, which is essentially the aim of PSM. Subgroup analyses can sometimes be fround upon in the RCT setting as the study is often not powered to answer these post hoc questions. Nevertheless doing a structured subgroup analysis in your setting (eg only stores with > or <100k revenue etc) would seem like an adequate approach. You can then increase complexity

Comment: Hi @I.V you might want to do a proper experimental design a priori before you start the experiment of you are really concerned against covariate balancing, sample size and statistical power. PSM/matching might not the solution for this problem.